Is there a way to set OpenSSH and MIT Kerberos on windows without PuTTY?
I need to connect through OpenSSH from Windows to a remote Linux server using a Kerberos ticket.
I can:
Connect to the account through SSH after getting a ticket on a cygwin64 terminal with a certain .ssh/config and certain cygwin64/etc/krb5.conf file. Open this in a terminal within VSCode (But not load the server files in the VSCode file system).
Although not tried, people can do the same using PuTTY instead of cygwin.
Interestingly, I can also do this on my windows terminal itself! The server website provided the cygwin64 and PuTTY setups as a solution to Windows not having Kerberos. I, however, can run the kinit and klist commands within the windows terminal. I had downloaded a bunch of things - Including MIT Kerberos. Although am not too sure if I set it up right. (My server website asks me to include the kerberos5 config file to add to etc, but there is no such folder in windows.)
I can get the kerberos ticket, which validly is saved in the User/krb5cc_<User> file. However, I can not still access my account through the ssh. >ssh -vvv -Y user@server shows me connection to my server has been established. Thereafter, it tries to open a few files like id_rsa, id_ecdsa-cert, id_dsa (and more) at User/.ssh/
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

being the first message without failure. Therafter, it tries to access my server by my username and fails to find 2 ssh_known_hosts files. It goes on doing bunch of other stuff and finally ending into
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: GSS_S_FAILURE
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server: Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I believe there is some error in my ssh/openssh/MITKerberos configurations.
Could anyone please help me with accessing my remote account? Is there even a way to access it?
A different but related question:
How do I open the server on VSCode? I can access servers on vscode through ssh, password, but I have no clue how to go about Kerberos ticket authentication. To be honest I do not even understand how to clearly set any of these up and even how do these work in relation to each other. What are keys and tickets? How exactly do they work? Can I transfer them from user/servers/applications? I have a very vague understanding of how things work, but it is not so clear.
Any help?
For reference, https://uscms.org/uscms_at_work/physics/computing/getstarted/uaf.shtml#conda this is what I am trying to setup on Windows. Their Cygwin64 method works but seems to be incompatible with VSCode (unless I am just dumb enough to not know how to make things work.)

Does it necessarily have to be MIT Kerberos? The "official" Windows OpenSSH build uses SSPI (i.e. Windows native Kerberos).

Honestly, I have no clue. It seems to not work

Secondary answers

(My server website asks me to include the kerberos5 config file to add to etc, but there is no such folder in windows.)

MIT Kerberos always has a krb5.conf, although it is in a different location on Windows (and I think it may also look for the same settings in the Windows Registry instead of the .conf file).
If the website asks you to manually specify the KDC server address, 1) use the Network Identity Manager GUI to edit the configuration (sorry, I don't know whether the 'new' Leash32 GUI can do the same) and 2) tell your website's admins to set up proper DNS SRV records for automatic discovery (which FNAL.GOV realm already has, so manual configuration might not be needed).

Their Cygwin64 method works but seems to be incompatible with VSCode

VSCode doesn't use Kerberos directly; it only runs the ssh command, which ends up being the official Windows OpenSSH by default. You can trick it into using the Cygwin OpenSSH by changing the remote.SSH.path setting in VSCode and that might work.

What are keys and tickets?

"Keys" can refer to several different things. In this case you are probably referring to SSH authentication keys – RSA or ECDSA keypairs that SSH can use as your login credentials (as a very popular alternative to both Kerberos and traditional passwords). The server would have your 'public' key listed in the user account's .ssh/authorized_keys file, and the client would use the corresponding 'private' key to prove its identity.
"Tickets" are roughly what the name suggests – a temporary pass/permit/access token issued by Kerberos to let you access some server. With Kerberos, you never send your password to the SSH server itself; your password is only used to authenticate to the realm's KDC, which then provides you with a ticket that the SSH server will accept.
(Most likely, FNAL.GOV doesn't support key-based authentication because they keep user home directories on AFS so their cluster head nodes require a copy of your Kerberos credentials in order to access any of your files – at least, I believe that used to be the case in the past, but the linked webpage says that AFS is being phased out.)
Primary answer

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5


The "official" Windows OpenSSH build is ignoring your ticket cache because it has not been built to look for the MIT Kerberos libgssapi.dll – instead, being a Windows component, it has been built to use SSPI (i.e. Windows native Kerberos).
So if you specifically want to use MIT Kerberos, then you'll need a completely different OpenSSH build – such as that from Cygwin. As mentioned, you should be able to make VSCode use the Cygwin OpenSSH by changing the remote.SSH.path setting.
But if you only need Kerberos in general, then Windows can use in fact Kerberos for non-Active-Directory clients and servers, but it takes slightly more configuration compared to AD.

Note one major difference between Windows Kerberos and MIT Kerberos: Whereas MIT Krb5 will "canonicalize" the server name in a few different ways (applying both forward DNS canonicalization and rDNS canonicalization), Windows Kerberos does neither of those and will exactly use your provided hostname for obtaining the Kerberos ticket.
That is to say, while MIT Kerberos will automatically expand box to box.example.com, Windows Kerberos will not. Check your MIT Kerberos klist output to see what tickets it has actually obtained so that you'll know which is the correct server name to SSH to.

Actually enable Kerberos authentication in your SSH client configuration (independent of the other steps):
~\.ssh\config
Host *.example.com
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    # Delegation is somewhat risky, but FNAL's setup likely requires it,
    # so enable it separately.
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes

Add Host sections that would match the actual server names that you're planning on using in the command line. For example, if you just do ssh web1 then you would need Host web1 (or maybe Host *).
The webpage you've linked actually has a more fleshed out example – scroll back up to the "SSH configuration file" section.

IF the Kerberos realm is a non-Active-Directory realm, mark it as such so that Windows will know to not try contacting the AD Netlogon service:
sudo ksetup /AddRealmFlags EXAMPLE.COM

The presence of the entry (not any specific flag) marks the realm as "MIT realm" to Windows (which really means "non-AD realm"). You might need to reboot after making the change, as Windows caches lookup results or failures for a few hours.
The FNAL.GOV realm in your webpage has DNS SRV records for the Kerberos KDCs, so Windows will be able to discover them automatically. If for some reason you need to specify them manually, use ksetup /AddKdc for that.
(likely not needed)
sudo ksetup /AddKdc EXAMPLE.COM i-krb-7.fnal.gov

Finally, FNAL.GOV might want Kerberos delegation enabled (i.e. sending a copy of your Kerberos credentials to the server, so that it could use them for further connections). This is risky so by default Windows limits which servers may ask for it, requiring a special flag set by realm admin. But if you find that ssh refuses to do it even with GSSAPI­Delegate­Credentials enabled, you may need to tell Windows to "trust all servers":
(might or might not be needed)
sudo ksetup /AddRealmFlags EXAMPLE.COM Delegate

From what I remember, FNAL.GOV used to require delegation as they kept user home directories on AFS so their cluster head nodes required a copy of your Kerberos credentials in order to access any of your files – but the linked webpage says that AFS is being phased out, so delegation might not be necessary anymore.

If you're doing this from a local Windows account (i.e. currently logged in as a non-Active-Directory account), then you will need to store your Kerberos password in the Windows Credential Manager, so that SSPI would be able to obtain Kerberos tickets for programs which don't do Windows-style interactive password prompting (such as OpenSSH-for-Windows).
cmdkey /add:*.example.com /user:fred@EXAMPLE.COM /pass

The password is stored for specific names. As with the ssh client, you need to /add it for the actual server name you're connecting to – if you SSH to blah.example.com, then add *.example.com, but if you SSH to just 'blah' then use /add:blah.


With GSSAPIAuthentication enabled and Windows Kerberos set up, you should be able to just ssh to the server. The setup will also be recognized by PuTTY and Firefox (though you have set those to use MIT libgssapi, but they both can also use Windows SSPI).

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Could you please help me out with setting the SSH on remote up?
If I open the cygwin64 terminal and ssh into my account, it does that since the ticket is right there.
I changed the remote.SSH.path to my cygwin64 ssh.exe path and the SSH config path to the cygwin64 path. It still showed up the same permission denied error. I updated the MIT Kerberos ticket. And somehow, this time, it worked! Except, it couldn't connect and showed  WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!. On the FNAL website, this is indicated as a ssh config error.

How exactly should I setup VSCode? I saw another post that tricks it into using PuTTY and echoing ssh to make it think it is indeed just ssh. Is there a way I can first test things in windows itself? Perhaps use cygwinssh command through a custom alias without using the actual cygwin terminal?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470070/how-to-set-preferred-kerberos-gssapi-library-in-ssh-config-file
I configured things for Windows SSH client, setting up the cmdkey, ssh/config, realmflags, generating the MIT Kerberos ticket (although not necessary since it is of no use.)I also had extra configurations as per https://serverfault.com/questions/1169586/is-there-a-way-to-set-openssh-and-mit-kerberos-on-windows-without-putty/1169594#1169594
and got

C:\Users\DELL>ssh -Y user@domain
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
--blah blah--
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
something.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in C:\Users\DELL/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ED25519 key in C:\Users\DELL/.ssh/known_hosts:9
Host key for something.some.gov has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.

Idk if this is correct, on cygwin I would first kinit user@FNAL.GOV; password
ssh user@something.FNAL.GOV
And login automatically.
As you said, I configured everything, even optional things for FNAL.GOV.
Idk if I have to do the same for something.FNAL.GOV. I didn't do that for cygwin64 and it still worked with configuration of just *.FNAL.GOV for user *@FNAL.GOV
Idk what is wrong with this.
It would be much nicer to make the SSH client on windows available natively to work since it works directly with VSCode... no 3rd party jargon required.
But ig I will have to use PuTTY anyways.
